# Conditional statments in r in two columns

Tags: r

I have two columns, `weight` and `area`.  I want to create two columns as follows:

1. out1: If `weight` > 12, top, else down.
2. out2: If `area` > -0.5, insert a value of 0. Otherwise round the absolute value of `area` with 0.5 mapping to 1.

Desired output:

```
       weight   area    out1    out2
           12      3    down       0
           13   -0.4     top       0
           11    2.5    down       0
           17   -0.5     top       1
           16   -3.7     top       4
           14   -1.2     top       1
           11   -4.8    down       5
```

Comment: You could try `ifelse` here

Comment: I did my best, but I was unsuccessful. Can you help please.

Comment: I posted a solution below. You could also do this in `base R` with `transform` or `within`

Comment: can you give me codes without using a package please

Comment: Could you also include what you tried in the question?

Comment: I have corrected the table

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a factor column to dataframe based on a conditional statement from another column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570302/how-to-add-a-factor-column-to-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-statement-from-an)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
transform(df, out1=c('down', 'top')[(weight>12)+1L], 
                   out2= ifelse(area >-0.5, 0, abs(round2(area,0))))
#   weight area out1 out2
#1     12  3.0 down    0
#2     13 -0.4  top    0
#3     11  2.5 down    0
#4     17 -0.5  top    1
#5     16 -3.7  top    4
#6     14 -1.2  top    1
#7     11 -4.8 down    5
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, paste0('out',1:2) := list(c('down', 'top')[(weight>12)+1L],
               ifelse(area > -0.5, 0, abs(round2(area,0))))][]
```

where `round2` is (taken from [Round up from .5 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688717/round-up-from-5-in-r))

```
  round2 = function(x, n) {
  posneg = sign(x)
  z = abs(x)*10^n
  z = z + 0.5
  z = trunc(z)
  z = z/10^n
  z*posneg
   }
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this won't round the -0.5 to -1 ...  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688717/round-up-from-5-in-r

Comment: @jalapic Yes, the one in the link `round2` gives the expected result here

Comment: @user2684423 replace `round` by `round2` from the link jalapic provided to get the expected result as you showed

Comment: can you provide codes, i have used that link, but i got error

Comment: out 1 is ok- problem continue with out2, the values are different. Can you help please

Comment: @user2684423 Which values are different?  Initially, you had `-1` for the 4th row.  I don't know how it changes to 1 now

Comment: @user2684423  Just wrap it with `abs`. Updated the post

Comment: can you do it with data table please

Comment: @user2684423  Isn't that already posted there? `setDT(df)[, paste0('out',1:2) := list(c('down', 'top')[(weight>12)+1L], ifelse(area > -0.5, 0, abs(round2(area,0))))][]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do this using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
dt[, out1 := "down"][weight > 12, out1 := "top"]
dt[, out2 := floor(abs(area)+0.5)][area > -0.5, out2 := 0]
#    weight area out1 out2
# 1:     12  3.0 down    0
# 2:     13 -0.4  top    0
# 3:     11  2.5 down    0
# 4:     17 -0.5  top    1
# 5:     16 -3.7  top    4
# 6:     14 -1.2  top    1
# 7:     11 -4.8 down    5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(weight= c(12, 13, 11, 17, 16, 14, 11),
                 area  = c(3, -0.4, 2.5, -0.5, -3.7, -1.2, -4.8))

df$out1 <- ifelse(df$weight > 12, "top", "down")
df$out2 <- ifelse(df$area > -0.5, 0, floor(0.5 + abs(df$area)))

df

#   weight area out1 out2
# 1     12  3.0 down    0
# 2     13 -0.4  top    0
# 3     11  2.5 down    0
# 4     17 -0.5  top    1
# 5     16 -3.7  top    4
# 6     14 -1.2  top    1
# 7     11 -4.8 down    5
```

Comment: What type of error?  Just ran this in a clean session and no issues on my end?

Comment: out 2- I reeve 000000 -2 -2-2-2 00000

Comment: I guess I'm questioning how you are trying to "round" -- how does -0.5 map to +1?

Comment: values between -0.5 and -1.00 will get 1. Thanks for your help Jason

Comment: I think if we transfer negative values to positive , this will be solved. Can you try it please?

Comment: @user2684423 modified the answer, I *think* it is the correct logic.

Comment: I did please see table

Comment: @user2684423 Done. Not changing it again.