# Adding conditional attributes to data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I hope the question is posted correctly. A similar problem is faced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570302/how-to-add-a-factor-column-to-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-statement-from-an), even if it is slightly different about the expected result. 
I would like to create a 20 rows dataframe with 10 men and 10 women:

```
e6 <- data.frame(20)
e6 <- rep( c("man", "woman"), c(10, 10))
e6
[1] "man"   "man"   "man"   "man"   "man"   "man"   "man"   "man"  
[9] "man"   "man"   "woman" "woman" "woman" "woman" "woman" "woman"
[17] "woman" "woman" "woman" "woman"
```

Now I would like to create a column `e6$answer` where between the 10 men, 8 of them say "yes" and 2 of them "no". Between the 10 women: 3 of them say "yes" and 7 of them say "yes". I tried using the approach suggested at the link at the top of the post:

```
e6$answer <- ifelse(e6 == "man", rep( c("yes", "no"), c(8, 2)), 
             rep( c("yes", "no"), c(3, 7)))
```

Unfortunately, my attempt returns an error. Probably I am doing an error with the classes.

```
Warning message:
In e6$answer <- ifelse(e6 == "man", rep(c("yes", "no"), c(8, 2)),  :
  Coercing LHS to a list
```

Thank you very much for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `e6` is a character vector (see `class(e6)`), not a data frame. Thus, `ifelse` coerces it to a list. Try

```
e6 <- data.frame(gender = rep( c("man", "woman"), each=10))
e6$answer <- ifelse(e6 == "man", rep( c("yes", "no"), c(8, 2)), 
             rep( c("yes", "no"), c(3, 7)))
```